Expressing the cosine rule with the sine function
I have a triangle with sides of length $\left(x + y\right)$, $\left(x + z\right)$ and $\left(y + z\right)$. We can get the angle near $x$ by the Cosine Rule:
$$
\alpha\left(x,y,z\right) =\arccos\left(\frac{\left[x + y\right]^{2} + \left[x + z\right]^{2} - \left[y + z\right]^{2}}{2\left[x + y\right]\left[x + z\right]}\right)
$$

I found a reference ( link below ) saying that the formula can be rewritten as
$$
\alpha\left(v,u,w\right) = 2 \arcsin
\left(\sqrt{\frac{u}{v + u}\,\frac{w}{v + w}}\right)
$$

I cannot see the connection.
I am referring to the paper "Collins, Charles R., and Kenneth Stephenson. "A circle packing algorithm." Computational Geometry 25.3 (2003): 233-256." ( formula $1.1$ on page $236$ and formula $4.2$ on page $243$).

The second formula is leveraging the half-angle identity for sine: $$\sin^2\frac12\theta ;=; \frac12(1-\cos\theta)$$
